# AutoHotKey: Loop doesn't work if a key binding is defined before it

Tags: autohotkey

If I define a loop and a key binding after it, it works:

```
Loop {
  IfWinActive, Pixel Dungeon
  SetNumLockState, On
  WinWaitNotActive, Pixel Dungeon
    SetNumLockState, Off
  Sleep, 200
}

a::b
```

But if I define the key binding before the loop, the loop doesn't work anymore:

```
a::b
; RETURN doesn't help

Loop {
    ... doesn't work
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a::b` is a key remap, if you press "a" it sends "b". AHK replaces `a::b`  internally with two basic hotkeys, so there is an implicit `return` there. You have to place your code in the autoexecute section above or place it in an hotkey definition like:

```
+a::
    ; Loop here
return
```

Comment: Thanks! wasn't familiar with the autoexecute section, should've [RTFM](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)